# Unable to get Realtek NIC running at 1Gbps

Tags: networking, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet

I have a Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller.  I've just upgraded all cabling to Cat 6. I've set 1.0 Gbps Full Duplex in the Controller Properties (from Auto Negotiation), and I've got into my router and confirmed that it has a 1000Mbps connection. I downloaded the Realtek driver from the Realtek page.  The speed still registers as 100 Mbps in the Ethernet Status dialog on Win 10.

Does anyone have any other ideas? I've looked at numerous forums (including this one) and can't find any other suggestions.

Comment: The speed that Windows displays has no effect on the actual connection. It’s just what the driver reports. If you can, do a speed test with another (wired) device on the local network.

Comment: Quick test - does the NIC have lights on/near the socket? If so, green or orange? Also check the other end of the cable run for similar.

Comment: One light is green, one orange. It's plugged into a router, which only displays a single green light. It reports a 100Mbps connection on the web interface. I've just run LAN Speed Test (totusoft.com/lanspeed), and it reports writing 13.21, reading 92.61 (the target machine [linux] reports gigabit speed. Is this typical for a gigabit NIC?

Comment: Wait, _why_ are you setting the speed/duplex setting manually? This almost always has negative results.

Comment: To piggyback on @user1686's comment, gigabit requires auto-negotiation and most ethernet drivers stop at 100mbit full-duplex, since gigabit requires auto-negotiation AFAIK. If that doesn't resolve the issue, did you terminate the ethernet cables yourself _(e.g. crimp your own RJ45 connector)_? If so, it's often either a wiring mismatch or a bad connection with one or more wires when the RJ45 connector is crimped _(crimp a new RJ45 connector on the cable)_ - it could also be a bad cable, which you'd rule out by testing continuity between the respective pins on each end of the cable.

Comment: Thanks for help. Replaced the RJ45 socket and I've now got 1Gbps. Worked it out by bringing a PC home from work, and proved that the problem was with the wiring. The wall socket was one of those awful ones where you need to strip the ends of the wires and screw them down. Replaced it with a keystone jack.

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title. Instead post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. This will mark the question as resolved and will make the solution visible.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by replacing the terminal leading into the PC with a keystone jack. The old skirting wall mount socketrequired you to strip each wire and screw it and was prone to errors.